# Calling body_class and wp_nav_menu for a different post

Tags: wp-query, menus, query-posts, body-class

I need to be able to display `wp_nav_menu` and `body_class` for a page/post that isn't the current post.

For instance:

```
// current page/post is ID:100

wp_query/query_posts{

    // currently looping a page/post, i.e. ID:999

    wp_nav_menu(); // returns nav menu for ID:100
    body_class(); // returns body class for ID:100
}
```

From what I've learnt, it sounds like I will need to modify `global $wp_query` to get this to work. I have tried that, but seem to be getting nowhere fast.

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This approach sounds complex, hacky and not reliable, as there could be various filters/actions that might be skipped.

Two alternative semi-workarounds comes to mind, to get the `wp_nav_menu()` and `body_class()`, for a given post page:

1. Use the [HTTP API](https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) / Ajax to make a request for the post page and e.g. use a GET parameter to return only these values. This might be slow for many posts.
2. Generate these values when the post page is loaded and cache it for some time. We could e.g. store it with the [post meta API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Metadata_API) or use the [transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API), depending on our needs. We would have to keep in mind that the amount of traffic can vary for each post page.

Comment: Hi birgire, thanks for your reply. I should explain what my goal is here, we are creating a custom page cache / static site generator for our WP sites (to defeat that dreaded, slow WP initialisation). In our old code, we would `wp_remote_get` every single page/post on the site to store them into our cache. This worked just fine, and is the simplest/most problem free option. Unfortunately, this breaks on some servers when the execution time exceeds the limit (100 posts to query = 100 seconds). By using a `wp_query` / `query_posts` loop, it reduces the time significantly, and works fine.

Comment: This is the code we use instead of `wp_remote_get`, it basically just calls the template that the requests post/page uses.  `ob_start(); include(locate_template(basename(get_page_template()))); $pageData[$postID]['html'] = ob_get_clean();`

Comment: I thought there were many plugins out there that can cache and serve pages as static HTML pages? There are also things like [Varnish HTTP cache](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) that can speed up things. And just switching to PHP7 can make things better ;-) @rorymorris89

Comment: yeah there's a few plugins that we reviewed before deciding to do it ourselves. The problem with most caching plugins, is that they still run WordPress's core, all of the plugins etc, on every page-load. Sure, they optimise the database optimisation for the content creation, but that's only a small part of the load.  What we're doing, is basically bouncing the whole site down into a pages.json file. This then gets loaded on the front-end with AJAX (it's about 70kb for 40+ pages), so subsequent page changes are instant - it works quite nicely (this old method uses wp_remote_get).

Comment: hehe now comes the silly question: why use WordPress and not jekyll or it's friends ;-) I wonder if you could use wp-cli to avoid the script timeout? What about using a storage, like MongoDB, Redis, CoucheDB for your json objects? Then you could update each post item when needed and not have get all the posts pages at ones into a huge single json file? ps: there's the wp-api-menu [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-api-menus/) for menus but I don't think it handles per post cases. @rorymorris89

Comment: Some very fine suggestions, thank you - I'll look into those options. Currently we have two caching routes in our back-end; 1) a full cache regeneration which starts from the press of a button, and 2) a single post replacement in the cache when a single post gets saved. Just reading into wp-cli now, thanks again.

Comment: ps: Interesting [article](https://wptavern.com/wordexpress-project-experiments-with-bringing-graphql-to-wordpress) published today at wptavern about [WordExpress](https://github.com/ramsaylanier/WordExpress) - might give some ideas ;-)   @rorymorris89